# Javascript style editor toolbar for any html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a JavaScript widget to edit font-related and border-related CSS properties of **any given** html element.

I imagine it would produce a toolbar like rich text editors have, except that I can could choose the element to apply the style to at the widget initialization time.

I have been looking through search engines with no success. jQuery based libraries are preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I dont understand completely. But;

If you want to make Javascript-Run console, check this page(look at bottom) :

http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html